# What to do with layer of fat on pork spareribs?

Tags: pork, slow-cooking, ribs

So I got a nice big rack of ribs from an excellent butcher, and it has a fairly thick layer of fat.
[image]

Previously when I've bought ribs for smoking/slow cooking, That fat hasn't been there, and the ribs have been ready to receive my spice rub.

So my question is this:
What should/could I do with this fat?
Since I'll be putting it in my Kamado for slowcooking, I'd normally prepare the ribs similar to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFqzKyiCXIc&t=152s) as seen in this picture [image]

Currently I'm thinking of trimming most of the fat off and see how it goes...
Over the course of 4-6 hours, it should rend nicely, but I also want my spice rub on the meat itself...

Suggestions please? :-D

Comment: OMG that looks tasty!  If you don't want the fat you can ship it to my bitcoin address.

Comment: It *was* very tasty, and was a great success with my guests ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you get the importance of the fat rendering but still want the spice rub on the meat. I would trim the skin and fat off in one piece, if possible, using a very sharp filet knife. (A small amount of fat left on the meat is okay.)

Then rub your spice mix over all sides of the meat. Place the fat cap back on the meat where you removed it. On the top of the skin/fat season with salt or your spice rub and go to cooking.

The fat will render and you should still end up with well seasoned, moist, tender ribs. Bonus, you should get a well seasoned crispy skin. If the skin doesn't crisp enough with the cooking method, you can remove the fat cap when the ribs are done and place it on a pan under the broiler to finish the crisping.

Comment: It might be better to put the fat on a rack above, and let the fat drip down onto the meat ... if the cap's back in place, I suspect the smoke won't penetrate the meat.  In an oven, it probably wouldn't make a difference

Comment: That is an amazing idea....
I think @Joe has a point about the smoke not penetrating though, so I may have to order an extra rack urgently...

It is a Kamado, so it doesn't have a broiling option either...

Comment: @LarsPanzerbjrn : you could probably find some other way to get the fat above the meat ... maybe a few skewers (to either bridge the area where a rack would sit, or to make legs to suspend the fat cap)

Comment: I got an extra raised rack, so I will try that, and report back on how it went. Thanks to you both for your suggestions...